# What is the equivalent resource in Chef for Block in ansible?

Tags: ansible, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have some ansible playbook which is using Block module and same i want to rewrite in Chef. But not able to find equivalent resource in Chef.

Example Source code:

```
tasks:
 - name: Handle the error
   block:
     - debug:
         msg: 'I execute normally'
     - name: i force a failure
       command: /bin/false
     - debug:
         msg: 'I never execute, due to the above task failing, :-('
   rescue:
     - debug:
         msg: 'I caught an error, can do stuff here to fix it, :-)'
```

**Note:** Above lines are the example code. It can be any line of code. but my requirement to know which chef resource i can use to replace block syntax ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Blocks` allow for logical grouping of tasks and in play error handling. Mostly used to apply single condition to multiple tasks which can be achieved by `If` condition in Chef like.

```
if node[:platform_family].include?("rhel")

  package 'httpd'

  service 'httpd' do
   action [:enable, :start]
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct equivalent, at least for the `rescue` functionality. For grouping, you just use normal Ruby coding practices.